Unity exporting only one value to json?
I'm making a Unity Game with TikTokLive Unity library, it's my first time using Dictionaries and Jsons in Unity so I might be doing something very wrong.... The whole code I will be sending below is included in the GiftRow class.
This is the initialization of the dictionary
public class GiftRow : MonoBehaviour
{
        private Dictionary<string, int> usersCoinsTotal = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        private void Awake()
        {
            LoadFromFile();

        }

Here is the Init function that is called somewhere else when someone gifts
public void Init(TikTokGift gift)
{
    OnGiftUpdateCoins(gift.Sender.UniqueId, GetGiftValue(gift.Gift.Name));
    Gift = gift;
    Gift.OnAmountChanged += AmountChanged;
    Gift.OnStreakFinished += StreakFinished;
    txtUserName.text = $"{Gift.Sender.UniqueId} sent a {Gift.Gift.Name}!";
    txtAmount.text = $"{Gift.Amount}x";
    RequestImage(imgUserProfile, Gift.Sender.AvatarThumbnail);
    RequestImage(imgGiftIcon, Gift.Gift.Image);
    // Run Streak-End for non-streakable gifts
    if (gift.StreakFinished)
        StreakFinished(gift, gift.Amount);
}

OnGiftUpdateCoins and GetGiftValue functions
private void OnGiftUpdateCoins(string username, int coins)
{
    if (usersCoinsTotal.ContainsKey(username))
    {
        usersCoinsTotal[username] += coins;
        Debug.Log($"{username}'s coin value updated to: {usersCoinsTotal[username]}\n");
    }
    else
    {
        usersCoinsTotal.Add(username, coins);
        Debug.Log($"{username}'s coin value created as: {coins}\n");
    }
    ExportSaveObjectsToJson();
}

public int GetGiftValue(string giftName)
{
    if (giftValues.ContainsKey(giftName))
    {
        return giftValues[giftName]; // Return the coin value if the gift exists
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Gift not found: " + giftName); // Log a warning if the gift is not in the dictionary
        return 0; // Return 0 if the gift doesn't exist
    }
}

ExportSaveObjectsToJson function
public void ExportSaveObjectsToJson()
{
    // Convert the list of SaveObject to JSON string
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usersCoinsTotal, Formatting.Indented);

    // Define the path to save the JSON file
    //string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/saveObjects.json";
    string path = "D:/saveObjects.json";

    // Write the JSON to the file
    File.WriteAllText(path, jsonString);

    Debug.Log("Save objects exported to JSON file at: " + path);
}

Also json doesnt save every time I close the game, for which I created this function
private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    Debug.Log("Game quit");
    //foreach (var i in usersCoinsTotal.Values)
    //{
    //    Debug.Log(i);
    //}
    ExportSaveObjectsToJson();
    foreach (var kvp in usersCoinsTotal)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}");
    }
}

Thanks for reading this far :)
Issue is when I run the game, it connects to the stream successfully and the game shows all the gifts, however when I close the game, there is only one value in the dictionary (last gifter, username and coins he sent, not total coins added up, but just last gift amount of coins), same is in the json, just one gifter is shown.
Here is the whole json file, this is the last gifter before I closed the game:
{
  "девочка1234590": 1
}

I tried leaving the initialization of dictionary in class and create like 'new' dictionary in start and Awake functions, in that case no gifts get saved, it just doesn't work at all in that case. I want the code to basically save the username and if the username isn't already inside of the dictionary create a new key and value for it. If it however is there, then just update the existing value for that username.

Everything looks fine, at least from the code that you shared. When do you create an object with this GiftRow behaviour? Do you make a new class for every gift, or is there only one GiftRow created on startup?

Same question as @ipodtouch0218. Init function implies you are creating a new GiftRow on each new gift and initializing it, but then the Dictionary is a member function so each GiftRow instance will have their own dictionary, which will always only have one username in it and it's the one of the user whose gift created this new GiftRow instance and it will always overwrite the same file on disk. So the last GiftRow you instantiate, will also write the last user to gift you coins to disk.

@ipodtouch0218, GiftRow is created once, it is called when someone sends a gift.

@NPatch  I initalized dictionary on start of class, not in the GiftRow method?

Could you post the code that handles the instantiation of the GiftRow object anyways? We're thinking that might be where the bug is.

If not, just open it with a debugger and go through all the places you mess with usersCoinsTotal. Something either clears the dictionary or recreates it. You can also go through with the debugger while a gift is given and check usersCoinsTotal contents at every step, till you see it clear. The only other case I can think of is that you might have forgotten about a place that creates a GiftRow instance as a default, which also ends up doing it. Can't think of anything else with the code given(e.g. what do you do in StreakFinished?).

A bit unrelated, but be careful with OnApplicationQuit for saving data. At the very least, it is never called when the app crashes or is killed by the user via Task Manager. And this becomes especially true on mobile where apps pretty much never close normally. Instead, either the os kills them, or the user swipes them out.

@Vladimir wow, thanks that actually saved me a lot of debugging! In that case I guess I will just add a save button or something.

I actually fixed this, probably not my best work, but I create a new dictionary that loads values from json every gift event. I mean, for my purposes it should be fine, but if someone has better ideas they are welcome :D

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
